# How do I keep the same Azure Function active when I perform multiple calls?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to perform multiple calls an Azure Function which uses the exact same session if I call it multiple times over a time period of 1 hour. How do I do this?

Background:
I'm using a function GetAccessToken() which connects to the OAuth endpoint to retrieve the token. I want to prevent connecting to the OAuth Server 20 times in a few minutes, hence want to hold the AccessToken in the Azure Function and return it when necessary.

Example
3 calls to: https://funcapp12930.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1
Call 1 After 30 minutes: AccessToken 'bearer ey03193013459'
Call 2 After 59 minutes: AccessToken 'bearer ey03193013459'
Call 3 After 2 hours: AccessToken 'bearer ba204345314555'

Comment: Is persisting state in some volatile storage an option?

Comment: Yes, we can use Blob Storage to store a token file and when it's older than one hour simply replace it.

Comment: I was thinking more like Redis Cache or Cosmos DB. Both of them have TTL functionality so that your access token will auto delete after a certain amount of time (say 1 hour).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as Gaurav suggests in the comments.

- When the request comes in check the cache (Redis or Cosmos db)
- If it is not in the cache get the token and store it in the cache
- return the token

However, you are introducing a potential security problem. If the cache is not secured then it is possible for someone to get the token.

You need to compare the benefit of reducing calls to the OAUTH server against the security risks and extra cost of the Cache.

Comment: Is it much safer if I just store in the Azure Storage Container? It will certainly cost less.

Comment: On the security side it is about the same, since the problem is if the storage account or cache is not locked down properly. Here is an article on how to use managed identity between Azure Functions and Azure Storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-storage-managed-identity/using-managed-identity-between-azure-functions-and-azure-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Use durable functions and orchestration pattern.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp

You create a main azure function that gets the access token and then activate the other function 20 times and pass the token to each run.

Comment: Will the Azure Function be re-triggered completely if I run it for the 21st time?

Comment: Its not retriggered, it just continues. It sleeps waits for the 20, wakes up. You are not charged for the wait